# How to preserve date created while moving files to downloads folder?

Tags: terminal, folders, data-transfer, file-transfer

So I was transferring some files from my old mac to new one using an external drive. I was able to get all the files with their dates preserved to my **users** folder, however while moving them to downloads they change to present date and time. I understand that this must be a downloads folder property of resetting date to when it was first added, but is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: Have you tried copying or moving the Downloads folder itself rather than the files in the folder? You may need to delete the Downloads folder first in the target disk for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Open `terminal`, and use the command line to copy files using `cp` with the option `-a` (archive, copies recursively); e.g.,

```
$ cp -a /Volumes/ExternalDrive/backups/my_dir ~/Downloads/
$ ls -la ~/Downloads/my_dir
```

For details on `cp` options and what they mean, in terminal, run `man cp`